# Why am I getting exception "IOException: ZIP entry size is too large" when trying to open an Excel file using Apache POI?

Tags: java, excel, apache, zip, apache-poi

The problem is the same as described [here](http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/IOException-quot-ZIP-entry-size-is-too-large-quot-when-downloading-excel-file-td4651492.html)

But since no solution found there, trying to reopen the topic here?
In short, I'm using Apache POI 3.8. I have a ***.xlsm** file with Macros in it. I am trying to open this file while the application is deployed, but getting the error inside "**XSSFWorkbook**" constructor which says that "**ZIP entry size is too large**". 
   The strange part is that I am able to perform that operation locally in my IDEA without any problems. 
   Would appreciate if someone would share the ideas of what is happening, if any had such issue in the past.

Comment: What JDK versions are used on your app server and local machine?

Comment: Should be 1.6 on both

Comment: And the vendors? You had better make sure, because it is important here. Also, not sure it POI uses the zip support from the JDK or commons-compress, but if the latter, what versions on both matchines?

Comment: Apache POI 3.8 is a little old, does it work better with 3.10?

Comment: did you use large request passed by servlet to get that file? try to minimize the request and see what happen.

Answer (score 3):

Glancing a bit through the related code, my guess is that it depends on where the file is located.  Possibly if it is a File then poi is handling it differently than if it is some other source (e.g. in memory)?

If that is the case, then you could probably solve the problem by writing the file to a temporary file and then loading it into poi.  Specifically, if you create an XSSFWorkbook from a File, you should not hit this issue.  According to the javadoc, you do this:

```
   OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(path);
   XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(pkg);
   // work with the wb object
   ......
   pkg.close(); // gracefully closes the underlying zip file
```

Comment: Have tried that one also. But the same exception when reading from temporary file as well.

Comment: @LaRRy - can you show that exception?  looking at the source seems to indicate that you wouldn't use the same class when loading from a file.  (specifically ZipFileZipEntrySource vs ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource).

Comment: the exception trace is available through link in the description. (first 7 lines)

Comment: @LaRRy - yes, i looked at that, which is using ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.  can you show your exception?

Comment: I don't have it here, since I'm at home. But I'm pretty sure the exception is the same.

Comment: @LaRRy - looking at the code, if you open an XSSFWorkbook with a String path, you should not hit this issue.

Comment: Not with a String path - this constructor is deprecated. I have tried with a File or with an InputStream.

Comment: @LaRRy - updated with the non-deprecated way to do this.

Comment: yes, I remembered. Two ways with Constructor were: 1. From Resource input stream. 2. From new Temp file as InputStream. File was another way (not successful) to do that through WorbookFactory or something.

Comment: @LaRRy - any type of InputStream (File or resource) will cause the same issue.  You have to load it from a String path in order for it to work (as in the example i showed above).

Comment: Okay. I'll try that tomorrow. Thank you very much, jtahlborn, for your help.

Answer (score 3):

So the reason was that Maven was corrupting template file when building application archive.

Comment: Resources filtering must be disabled for binary resources!